# How would you name and/or describe this algorithm?

Tags: symmetric, classical-cipher, terminology

First up: this is not a decoding request or anything. This is about ***[terminology](/questions/tagged/terminology)***.

Twice per year, we email another department to ask for a new licence file for their software. They are always slow to reply. The licence files are encrypted, but I noticed only a couple of characters change between revisions. My 'home-grown crypto' sense tingled. I surmised the characters that changed might correspond to the expiry date in the plaintext.

Ciphertext:

```
GO9ETBBE
GO9ETCBE
GO9WTBBE
```

Plaintext:

```
20150101
20150601
20160101
```

You can see it's not a substitution cipher. However a particular character at a particular position is always mapped the same way. For example, '1' at the third position is always mapped to '9'.

I amused myself by reverse engineering the rest of the algorithm (Python code):

```
letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789 "
secrets = "C3H8NJ1AX5VRU 2F04KYDIS6PQMOG9TLB7EWZ"

def decrypt(ciphertext):
    plaintext = ""

    for i,x in enumerate(ciphertext):
        j = secrets.index(x)
        j -= i # offset moves backwards 1 each character
        j %= len(secrets)
        plaintext += letters[j]

    return plaintext

def encrypt(plaintext):
    ciphertext = ""

    for i,x in enumerate(plaintext):
        j = letters.index(x)
        j += i
        j %= len(secrets)
        ciphertext += secrets[j]

    return ciphertext
```

Anyway, **my questions are**:

1. Is there a name for the "a particular character at a particular position is always mapped the same way" assumption?
2. How would you describe the algorithm? Colloquially I'd call it a "substitution cipher with a rolling offset"

Comment: seems to me like a many time pad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I don't think there is a name for this special kind of property, but it is a clear hint for polyalphabetic substitution ciphers.
2. It is a special kind of polyalphabetic substitution cipher. The first alphabet is a normal random key, while each successive alphabet is generated by a one-character right shift of the previous alphabet. As a result there are as many alphabets as there are characters in the plaintext (or cipher text) alphabet.